# Ruby: Is it possible to define a class method in a module?

Tags: ruby

Say there are three classes: `A`, `B` & `C`. I want each class to have a class method, say `self.foo`, that has exactly the same code for `A`, `B` & `C`.

Is it possible to define `self.foo` in a module and include this module in `A`, `B` & `C`? I tried to do so and got an error message saying that `foo` is not recognized.

Comment: Ruby doesn't really have a concept of static methods. In ruby, all methods have a receiver object. It just may be a method that happens to have a `class` of `Class` or `Module`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
module Common
  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
end

class A
  extend Common
end

class B
  extend Common
end

class C
  extend Common
end

A.foo
```

Or, you can extend the classes afterwards:

```
class A
end

class B
end

class C
end

[A, B, C].each do |klass|
  klass.extend Common
end
```

Comment: Isn't `foo` an instance method of A, B, and C, in this case ?

Comment: As Andrew already pointed out, Ruby's methods are always instance methods. But in this case, instances are classes. So, `foo` is class instance method. You call it with class as a receiver: `A.foo`. From within A's instance methods, you can also use `self.class.foo`.

Comment: @MladenJablanović well, _instance_ is usually used to refer to the objects that a class generates, not to the class object itself. I propose calling them _class methods_ instead of _class instance methods_ to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's perhaps worth a mention that `class A; extend Common; end` is equivalent to `class A; singleton_class.include Common; end`.

Answer (score 126):

Yep

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def some_method
      # stuff
    end
  end
end
```

One possible note I should add - if the module is going to be ALL class methods - better off just using `extend ModuleName` in the Model and defining the methods directly in the module instead - rather than having a ClassMethods module inside the Module, a la

```
 module ModuleName
   def foo
     # stuff
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 35):

This is basic ruby mixin functionality that makes ruby so special.
While `extend` turns module methods into class methods, `include` turns module methods into instance methods in the including/extending class or module.

```
module SomeClassMethods
  def a_class_method
    'I´m a class method'
  end
end

module SomeInstanceMethods
  def an_instance_method
   'I´m an instance method!'
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include SomeInstanceMethods
  extend SomeClassMethods
end

instance = SomeClass.new
instance.an_instance_method => 'I´m an instance method!'

SomeClass.a_class_method => 'I´m a class method'
```

Comment: Thanks for showcasing the difference between `include` and `extend`.

Answer (score 31):

Rails 3 introduced a module named `ActiveSupport::Concern` which has the goal of simplifying the syntax of modules.

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def some_method
      # stuff
    end
  end
end
```

It allowed us to save a few lines of "boilerplate" code in the module.

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to extend Oliver's answer
Define Class methods and instance methods together in a module.

```
module Foo
 def self.included(base)
   base.extend(ClassMethods)
 end
 module ClassMethods
   def a_class_method
     puts "ClassMethod Inside Module"
   end
 end

 def not_a_class_method
   puts "Instance method of foo module"
 end
end

class FooBar
 include Foo
end

FooBar.a_class_method

FooBar.methods.include?(:a_class_method)

FooBar.methods.include?(:not_a_class_method)

fb = FooBar.new

fb.not_a_class_method

fb.methods.include?(:not_a_class_method)

fb.methods.include?(:a_class_method)
```