# Why 'self' method of module cannot become a singleton method of class?

Tags: ruby

```
module Test
  def self.model_method
    puts "this is a module method"
  end
end

class A
  include Test
end

A.model_method
```

this will be error with:

> undefined method `model_method' for A:Class (NoMethodError)

But when I use metaclass of A. it works:

```
module Test
  def model_method
    puts "this is a module method"
  end
end

class A
  class << self
    include Test
  end
end

A.model_method
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is that possible to define a class method in a module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699355/is-that-possible-to-define-a-class-method-in-a-module)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to have both class methods and instance methods mixed into a class when including a module, you may follow the pattern:

```
module YourModule
  module ClassMethods
    def a_class_method
      puts "I'm a class method"
    end
  end

  def an_instance_method
    puts "I'm an instance method"
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
end

class Whatever
  include YourModule
end

Whatever.a_class_method
# => I'm a class method

Whatever.new.an_instance_method
# => I'm an instance method
```

Basically to over-simplify it, you `extend` to add class methods and you `include` to add instance methods.  When a module is included, it's `#included` method is invoked, with the actual class it was included in.  From here you can `extend` the class with some class methods from another module.  This is quite a common pattern.

See also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: https://tenzinchemi.in/include-extend-and-then-get-fancy-cla26qh5a001b08l6cc139007

Answer (score 11):

Including a module is analogous to copying its instance methods over.

In your example, there are no instance methods to copy to `A`. `model_method` is actually an instance method of `Test`'s singleton class.

---

Given:

```
module A
  def method
  end
end
```

This:

```
module B
  include A
end
```

Is analogous to this:

```
module B
  def method
  end
end
```

When you think of it this way, this makes perfect sense:

```
module B
  class << self
    include A
  end
end

B.method
```

Here, the methods are being copied to the `B` module's singleton class, which makes them the "class methods" of `B`.

Note that this is exactly the same thing as:

```
module B
  extend A
end
```

---

In reality, the methods are not being copied; **there is no duplication**. The module is simply included in the method lookup list.

Comment: For beginners like me, this discussion of the difference between extend and include at http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/ was helpful when read in conjunction with this post.