# Define class and instance methods at once - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like:

```
module MyLog

  def log
    unless @log
      @log = Logger.new(log_path)
      @log.formatter =  proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
        "#{datetime} #{msg}\n"
      end
    end
    @log
  end

end
```

To be reused between other classes like this:

```
Class A
  def self.log_path; 'log/a.log' end
  def log_path; 'log/a.log' end
  include MyLog
  extend  MyLog

  def some_method
    log.debug 'some thing'
  end

  def self.some_class_method
    log.debug 'in a class method'
  end

end
```

Is there a shorter way than those four lines at start of class A?

## Another thing

I would like to log by batches:

```
def expire
  expired_ids = []
  failed_ids  = []

  all.each do |event|
    if event.expire # saves record
      expired_ids << event.id
    else
      failed_ids << event.id
    end
  end

  log.debug "These ids were expired: #{ expired_ids }"
  log.debug "These ids failed to expire: #{ failed_ids }"
end
```

Is there a way I can do this cleanly? Separating logging from method logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `included` hook to automatically define class methods and instance methods:

```
module MyLog

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(Methods)
    base.send(:include, Methods)
  end

  module Methods
    def log_path; 'log/a.log' end

    def log
      unless @log
        @log = Logger.new(log_path)
        @log.formatter =  proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
          "#{datetime} #{msg}\n"
        end
      end
      @log
    end
  end

end
```

Like this, both class and instance methods will be automatically defined once the module gets included.

For your second problem, use `partition` and return the values, then log them:

```
def expire
  all.partition(&:expire)
end
```

Then, where you call `expire`, you can log the return values:

```
def call_something
  expired, failed = expire
  log.debug "These ids were expired: #{expired.map(&:id)}"
  log.debug "These ids failed to expire: #{failed.map(&:id)}"
end
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what I've been doing recentrly when faced with problems like yours:

```
class A
  class << self
    include MyLog

    def log_path
      'log/a.log'
    end
  end

  delegate :log_path, :log, to: "self.class"
end
```

Otherwise, choosing the best programing approach depends on your situation, on how often you are going to reuse the script, how many times will you have to refactor it during its lifetime, and so on. But in any case, please, don't try to save the *lines* of code, try to save the trouble to yourself when you are reading the code next time after yourself.

As for your second question, the main dilemma you are facing is, whether it is worth bother for you to introduce Events class:

```
class Events < Array
  def foobar
    each_with_object [[], []] do |event, (expired_ids, failed_ids)| 
      ( event.expire ? expired_ids : failed_ids ) << event.id
    end
  end
end
```

And then when the time comes:

```
def expire
  expired_ids, failed_ids = Events[ all ].foobar
  log.debug "These ids were expired: #{ expired_ids }"
  log.debug "These ids failed to expire: #{ failed_ids }"
end
```

Comment: @Babai: I am replacing Java software with Ruby software doing the same thing :-)

Comment: Just a friendly note to say that `delegate` is part of ActiveSupport, not pure ruby, so this advice is more applicable to Rails than all ruby projects.

Answer (score 2):

If your log path is always supposed to be `log/<lower_case_class>.log`, you can implement that in your module and you should be fine.  When the module's methods are executed, self will still be the object the method was called on, so you can say self.class and get A not your module name.

Check out the accepted answer on this question for how to add methods to both your class as well as your objects of that class

[Why 'self' method of module cannot become a singleton method of class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039039/why-self-method-of-module-cannot-become-a-singleton-method-of-class)

You can use Enumerable#partition to break up your "all" (you didn't actually say where that came from in your code you posted)

```
expired, failed = all.partition(&:expire)
```