# Ruby modules and classes not working together

Tags: ruby

I have a module `Animal`:

```
module Animal
  def sit
    puts '*sitting*'
  end
end
```

and I am `including` that module in a class `Dog`.

```
class Dog
  include Animal
end

dog = Dog.new.sit
```

When running this, I get this error:

```
dog.rb:2:in <class:Dog>':
uninitialized constant Dog::Animal (NameError)  from
dog.rb:1:in <main>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheriting class methods from modules / mixins in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692961/inheriting-class-methods-from-modules-mixins-in-ruby)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Just a simple constant lookup error. The `Animal` constant needs to be visible to the `Dog` class. It needs to be defined first or defined in the same file using `require`.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing some possibilities:

A. You have the `Animal` body and `Dog` body in different files, and calling the former from the latter without loading or requiring the file

B. You the `Dog` definition followed by the `Animal` definition.

If either is the case, then resolve it.