# A function that injects a class level function

Tags: ruby

I write the same function repeatedly in my classes. Is there a way to declare a function once, and just reference the function declaration in each relevant class to have it become part of the class? I want to do something like:

```
def add_func
  expand self.new_func
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class A
  import "add_func"
end

A.new_func
# >> hello world
```

I'm looking to make a class method, not an instance method, but I'd be interested in knowing how to do both. What is the Ruby construct I am looking for?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693010/4537254) describes what you are looking for.

Comment: The construct you are looking for is "inheritance".

Comment: It does not seem to make sense. Where do you expect `"world"` to come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the methods like this:

```
module SomeModule
  def foo
    true
  end
end

class SomeClass
  extend SomeModule
end

SomeClass.foo
```

Comment: This is almost right, def foo instead of def self.foo is what extends the class, please confirm

Comment: You can just `extend SomeModule` instead of `include SomeModule` and remove the `included` callback.

Comment: What @Stefan said because right now `foo` is added as an instance method and again as a class instance method. e.g. `SomeClass.foo == SomeClass.new.foo` in this case I guess that works but in most real world cases extend and include serve very different purposes

Answer (score 0):

You cann package individual methods into their own modules and extend them:

```
module MyModule
  module NewFunc
    def new_func
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
end

class A
  extend MyModule::NewFunc
end

A.new_func
```

With some metaprogramming / monkeypatching you could make a way to extend only certain methods of a module, but I think the approach I have shown works good enough.

If you wanted to make it so individual methods can be imported, or you can import all of them, you can do it like so:

```
module MyModule
  module NewFunc
    def new_func
      puts "hello"
    end
  end

  module NewFunc2
    def new_func2
      puts "hello2"
    end
  end

  include NewFunc, NewFunc2 # this adds them to MyModule directly
end

class A
  extend MyModule
end

A.new_func
A.new_func2
```